# Increment and return number based on user input

Tags: loops, clojure

So I have a vector of questions and want to increment and return a number based on the user's input. It's giving me trouble and I figure it's because of a lack of understanding of Clojure and it's ideals. Here is as close as I've gotten, but all I get returned is 0.

```
(defn print-questions [questions]
    (let [number 0]
        (doseq [question questions]
            (println question)
                (let [x (read-line)]
                    (if (= (.toLowerCase x) "y")
                        (inc number)
                        (println "No"))))
    number))
```

Comment: `(inc number)` is more like `number + 1`. The if is similar to `( x.toLowerCase().equals("y") ? number + 1 : System.out.println("No") )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clojure does not use variables as you encounter in imperative languages so statements like (inc x) **return a new value one higher than x, while leaving x alone** rather than changing x in place.

As written this code means:

```
 (defn print-questions [questions]
    (let [number 0]

      ;; start with zero every time
      ;; don't carry any information forward between iterations of the loop
      (doseq [question questions]
        (println question)
        (let [x (read-line)]
          (if (= (.toLowerCase x) "y")
            (inc number)   ;; this DOES NOT change the value in number
            (println "No"))))
      number))  ;; when you are all done, return the original value of number
```

This is great for cases where many threads are working on the same data, though it does lead to a somewhat different way of looking at things.

One way to write something very similar would be to loop through the questions while passing the current value of number from each iteration to the next like so:

```
user=> (defn print-questions [questions]
  #_=>         (loop [number 0 remaining-questions questions]
  #_=>           (println remaining-questions)
  #_=>           (if (seq remaining-questions)
  #_=>             (let [x (read-line)]
  #_=>               (if (= x "y")
  #_=>                 (do (println "yes")
  #_=>                     (recur (inc number) (rest remaining-questions)))
  #_=>                 (do (println "No")
  #_=>                     (recur number (rest remaining-questions)))))
  #_=>             number)))
#'user/print-questions
user=> (print-questions ["who" "what" "when" "why"])
[who what when why]
y
yes
(what when why)
y
yes
(when why)
n
No
(why)
y
yes
()
3
```

which works, though it's a bit verbose. If instead we look at this as reducing a collection of questions into a number where each reduction stage adds either one of zero to the outcome it's a bit more compact:

```
user=> (defn print-questions [questions]
  #_=>         (reduce (fn [answer question]
  #_=>                   (println question)
  #_=>                   (if (= "y" (read-line))
  #_=>                     (inc answer)
  #_=>                     answer))
  #_=>                 0
  #_=>                 questions))
#'user/print-questions
user=> (print-questions ["who" "what" "when" "why"])
who
y
what
n
when
y
why
y
3
```

reduce takes a function to do the actual work, a value to start with, and a list of inmputs. It then uses that function with the first value to create the new result, then uses the function with the second value to produce a new result and the third and so on until every value in the input has had a chance to affect the final result.

Comment: Where is the proper place to define number then?

Comment: I'm working on expanding the answer to describe other ways of going about this. In this case it's not really a question of defining number in a different place